# Disallow empty string as a valid value on a model with choices that include NULL

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-validation

I have the following model:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    RED = 'red'
    BLUE = 'blue'
    EMPTY_COLOR = None
    COLORS  = (
        (EMPTY_COLOR, '---'),
        (RED, 'red'),
        (BLUE, 'blue'),
    )

    color = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True,
                             choices=COLORS, default=EMPTY_COLOR)
```

I want the model to validate as valid (using `full_clean()` on an instance) if the color is set to `None` (or blue/red, of course) but not when it is set to an empty string. However, the empty string is happily allowed to be defined on the model and is saved in the database even though the choices are defined, in my view, to only ever be NULL, "red", or "blue".

Are my assumptions incorrect? How do I go about disallowing an empty string from being a valid value while keeping model validation working when the color is `None`?

Comment: You can't enforce that at the database level, however you can write your own `clean_color()` method on the model to check for the empty string value explicitly and raise a `ValidationError` if that's the case. This will ensure that when you validate the model (via a `ModelForm` for example), this will be caught. You could also do a final check when saving (override the `save()` method) to make sure no code saves an empty string (bypassing the validation).

Comment: Odd, I guess I understand why this isn't enforced at the DB level, but I would assume that if you define the set of choices to include three values, it shouldn't also accept a value that is not included in that set.

Comment: But you set `blank=True`, which is exactly what Django interprets as meaning empty string is allowed.

Comment: What you're doing is a bit against Django conventions: "Avoid using null on string-based fields such as CharField and TextField. If a string-based field has null=True, that means it has two possible values for “no data”: NULL, and the empty string. In most cases, it’s redundant to have two possible values for “no data;” the Django convention is to use the empty string, not NULL. "

Comment: @dirkgroten Thanks for that reference! I guess I will rework my fields to use `EMPTY_COLOR = ''` instead of `EMPTY_COLOR = None`. You can submit that as an answer if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing blank=True on the color field

```
color = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True,
                             choices=COLORS, default=EMPTY_COLOR)
```

or set it to blank=False